# Impala - CREATE TABLE after a WITH clause

Tags: sql, create-table, impala, with-statement

I have a query with several WITH clauses, then a `CREATE TABLE` :

```
    WITH TABLE_1 AS (
        SELECT * FROM SOMEWHERE_1
    ), TABLE_2 AS (
        SELECT * FROM SOMEWHERE_2

    (
        CREATE TABLE TABLE_3 AS
        (
            SELECT TABLE_1.*, TABLE_2.*
            FROM TABLE_1 
            INNER JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_2.key = TABLE_1.key
        )
    )
```

However I have the following error :

> Encountered: CREATE Expected: SELECT, VALUES, WITH CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

So I tried to put the CREATE statement first :

```
    CREATE TABLE_3 AS
    (
        WITH TABLE_1 AS (
            SELECT * FROM SOMEWHERE_1
        ), TABLE_2 AS (
            SELECT * FROM SOMEWHERE_2

        (
            SELECT TABLE_1.*, TABLE_2.*
            FROM TABLE_1 
            INNER JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_2.key = TABLE_1.key
        )
    )
```

But now I have the following error :

> AnalysisException: Could not resolve table reference: 'TABLE_1'

Note that :

- The above query WORKS without the "CREATE" statement
- My present situation is more complex than this simpe example, and I would like to keep the WITH statements, for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  I think this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_3 AS
    WITH TABLE_1 AS (
          SELECT * FROM SOMEWHERE_1
         ),
         TABLE_2 AS (
          SELECT * FROM SOMEWHERE_2
         )
    SELECT TABLE_1.*, TABLE_2.*
    FROM TABLE_1 INNER JOIN
         TABLE_2
         ON TABLE_2.key = TABLE_1.key;
```

Of course, you will have other problems, such as the `key` column being duplicated in the results -- and that should generate another error.  In practice, you should select exactly the columns that you want.

Comment: I am not sure why my 2nd attempt failed, but your solution works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This should fail. the syntax is not correct. `Create table <tablename>` is the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also do...

```
WITH TABLE_1 AS (
      SELECT * FROM SOMEWHERE_1
     ),
     TABLE_2 AS (
      SELECT * FROM SOMEWHERE_2
     )
SELECT TABLE_1.*, TABLE_2.* INTO TABLE_3
FROM TABLE_1 INNER JOIN
     TABLE_2
     ON TABLE_2.key = TABLE_1.key
```

It is much advised to always have a DDL handy and run `INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT * FROM CTE`